# Eclipse: indentation of single line comments after paste

Tags: eclipse, comments, indentation, copy-paste

In Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 when I paste some code containing single line comments the indentation of *the comment* is wrong, while the indentation of the code is correct.
Would I for example paste the following lines into some existing and correctly formatted/indented code...

```
// pasted comment
pasted.source.code();
```

... then this will happen:

```
   // original code
   foobar.somecode();
   // including comments
   allIsIndented.correctly();

// pasted comment
   pasted.source.code();

   // more original code
   foobar.qux();
```

- Note that the *actual text* of the comment seems to be indented corretly, but not the prefixing line comment markup (`//`).

After I hit [Ctrl] + [F] everything gets indented correctly, i.e. the one comment line above would move 3 chars to the right:

```
   ..
   allIsIndented.correctly();

   // pasted comment
   pasted.source.code();

   // more original code
   ..
```

This is driving me nuts. **Does anyone have a fix for this?**